# Clustering with Cross Validation in Rapid Miner

Tags: data-mining, k-means, cross-validation, rapidminer

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here but I'm hoping someone can help me out. I am trying to run x-validation in rapid miner with k-means clustering as my model.

I import my dataset, set a role of 'label' on one attribute, transform the data from nominal to numeric, then connect that output to the x-validation process. I then connect the training data to the k-means clustering model and connect the clustering model to the model for the testing data. I apply a model from the k-means model and then apply the performance process.

I keep getting an error that I need a special attribute 'label'.

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrect here, any help is appreciated.

Main Process: 
[image: main-process]

X-Validation process: 
[image: x-validation]

Error message: 
[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

X-Validation requires a label and a prediction. Clustering does not produce a prediction; it allocates examples to different clusters. To change the allocated cluster to a prediction, you can use the `Map Clustering on Labels` operator. Place this between the `Apply Model` and `Performance` operators.

If the number of clusters is different from the number of valid label values, the process will error.

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to check your Clustering in a validation, a bootstrap procedure might be appropriate for you as well. The bootstrapping can be easaliy archived using a loop and a sample operator. Attached is a process doing it.

If you use the Mapping from Clustering to label you just get the performance out of the validation. If you want to have the clustered examples you can use X-Prediction with the same trick.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="6.1.001-SNAPSHOT">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="6.1.001-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="6.1.001-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="60" name="Retrieve Sonar" width="90" x="112" y="75">
        <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//Samples/data/Sonar"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="loop" compatibility="6.1.001-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="76" name="Loop" width="90" x="313" y="75">
        <parameter key="iterations" value="10"/>
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="sample_bootstrapping" compatibility="6.1.001-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="76" name="Sample (Bootstrapping)" width="90" x="179" y="30"/>
          <operator activated="true" class="k_means" compatibility="6.1.001-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="76" name="Clustering (2)" width="90" x="313" y="30"/>
          <connect from_port="input 1" to_op="Sample (Bootstrapping)" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Sample (Bootstrapping)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Clustering (2)" to_port="example set"/>
          <connect from_op="Clustering (2)" from_port="cluster model" to_port="output 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_input 2" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_output 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_output 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Retrieve Sonar" from_port="output" to_op="Loop" to_port="input 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Loop" from_port="output 1" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```